# Azure Dedicated SQL Pool (Formerly SQL DW) is going to be remove from Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am using a Dedicated SQL Pool (Formerly SQL BW), I have a doubt if this is a new synapse or this will be removed from Azure in the future.
I need to know the difference between Dedicated SQL Pool (Formerly SQL BW) and Synapse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Synapse brings together data integration, enterprise data warehousing, and big data analytics and provides a unified experience in a single workspace. Dedicated SQL Pools are part of this workspace. However, Dedicated SQL Pool (Formerly SQL DW) will still be a stand-alone service in Azure for those who do not want all the other features of Synapse analytics.